# Change visibility of RadioButton item from code behind VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I have a `ASP.NET radiobutton` in my aspx web page and I'm using VB as my programming language.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoRecStatus" runat="server" Width="152px" CssClass="normalText"
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Open</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Closed</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want to change the visibility of the 2nd radio button <`asp:ListItem Value="0">Closed</asp:ListItem>` from a button click.

I tried using `rdoRecStatus.Items[1].Visible = True/False` to the above task and it shows an error.

Con you please tell me the right way to do the above task in `VB.NET`. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately There is no `Visible` properties for `<asp:ListItem>`, So we need to Look for some alternatives here to achieve this target.

**Method 1 :** Depend css to do this function like the following

```
 rdoRecStatus.Items(1).Attributes.Add( "hidden", "hidden" )
```

**Method 2 :** Remove that particular Item From the List:

```
 rdoRecStatus.Items.RemoveAt(1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Coool...! Happy to help you